# Possible to build this layout with views?

Tags: drupal, view

I'm trying to build this layout with views: http://screencast.com/t/3DFHcuwtfXV

Can anybody point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import this views to self: [Monthly listing nodes](http://drupalbin.com/17902) 
if i am not mistake, Date module should be also installed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this may also help you: http://drupal.org/project/archive